# RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 2s)

Tags: arrays, c, netbeans, integer, cygwin

I'm trying to store a large digit number (10^6) into an array. I'm first trying to get input as a string then store it in an integer array.
Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 1000000
int main()
{
    char ip[MAX];
    int num[MAX];
    int ch,i=0;
    
    while((ch = getchar()) !='\n') {
        ip[i++] = ch;
    }
    for(i = 0;i<=strlen(ip);i++) {
        num[i] = ip[i]-48;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is working fine when I am using a small number for MACRO MAX, for example 100. But I am getting an error with a large number. I am using netbeans. I tried this in vscode too but their I am getting Cygwin stack dump error.

Comment: You are likely causing a stackoverflow with large values for 'MAX'. Try to dynamically allocate the arrays instead of statically on the stack

Comment: Tip: For arrays that put *significant* pressure on the stack use `malloc()` or `calloc()` instead. Heap space is cheap. Stack is fairly limited. On Windows you get **only 1MB of stack space, period** for your entire app, even on a system with tens of GB of memory.

Comment: Thank you both. I didn't know about stack space. Your sugesstions worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen()`, expects a **NULL** terminated array of characters, meaning that you are missing a **\0** after your while loop.

This is also prone to overflow since you are not checking if your **i** value is smaller than **MAX - 1**.

After your while loop:

`ip[i] = 0`

or when declaring

`char ip[MAX] = {0}`